# Illustrator image size info

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-quality, image-format

I try compression to used images. How can i see images size (like 15MB, 20MB) to in my Illustrator file. Links window not show embeded images size.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke Document info window and choose Embedded images:

[image]

and multiple images:

[image]